# Maximum call stack size exceeded error on JQuery Autocomplete Lookup

Tags: jquery, html, django, lookup

I have the following code:

```
    var person_names = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('person_names').textContent);
    $('#autocomplete_person_names').val('');
    var selected_person = null;
    $('#autocomplete_person_names').autocomplete({
        lookup: person_names,
        showNoSuggestionNotice:true,
        maxHeight:200,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            selected_person = suggestion.value;
        }
    });
```

For some reason I get the uncaught type error `Maximum call stack size exceeded` in my console. When I check line by line, I found out the error is because of the following line:

```
lookup: person_names,
```

As far as I have found out by searches until now, the `Maximum call stack size exceeded` is because of recursive functions. But I cannot understand what kind of recursive behavior the `lookup` brings here. And if it has a recursive behavior (which seems it does) how can I resolve it in order to not get this error? The error prevents the rest of the jquery codes from running and that is disturbing.

Another thing: the variable `person_names` gives an array and works fine. And I am using this inside an html `template` inside a `Django` project.

The full error in console looks like this:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.map (jquery-3.3.1.js:462)
    at b.verifySuggestionsFormat (jquery.autocomplete.min.js:8)
    at b.setOptions (jquery.autocomplete.min.js:8)
    at new b (jquery.autocomplete.min.js:8)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery.autocomplete.min.js:8)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.js:354)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.js:189)
    at jQuery.fn.init.a.fn.devbridgeAutocomplete (jquery.autocomplete.min.js:8)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):3734)
    at c (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Comment: I believe it's happening because the browser cannot handle the person_names object. Did you test this with smaller datasets for the person_names? If so, try switching to an ajax based lookup.

Comment: That seems right. The array size is about 4000.  I will try that. I am just not familiar with ajax based lookup. Have to do some searching. Thanks

Comment: @HimanshuPant I checked and that was indeed what was causing the problem. I did something temporary until I can find out the ajax way. Used `slice()` to reduce the size of `person_names` dataset. Found out the size was not 4000 but surprisingly 169,000 (!!!). when I sliced it to 120,000 it worked fine (however ignoring the rest of the 49,000 fellas which is just sad :)) ). Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Also, I looked at the autocomplete library you're using, is basically called ajax autocomplete. You might want to have a look at jquery ui's autocomplete widget, It has more beginner friendly api documentation, using that you would basically provide a callback as the source option that sends an ajax request to the server with the hint that has been typed in, you're backend controller will do the lookup and respond with results. I hope this makes it easier.

Comment: @HimanshuPant Thanks again. Saved me some time. Will check that.